# Simple Ruby array strings concatenation?

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
array_name = ["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo" ]
```

I want to output the two strings concatenated. So end result is:

`=> "Hello`"

Ho do I do this? Please only post simple easy to grasp solutions?!

Comment: All numbers are being removed and a space is being appended?

Comment: I would like solution to include if characters exist statement. Thank u!

Comment: How are the two strings chosen?

Comment: To get the best form learning to code, you *should try yourself* then if you still cannot achieve your goal, explain where you are stuck. That way you will get high quality help that supports your learning, as opposed to just one assignment done the lazy way. That is also supposed to be how Stack Overflow works, but for some reason we have a lot of senior people willing to ignore that for now (or a change in policy where I missed the announcement!)

Comment: @NeilSlater I respect that!

Answer (score 2):

```
array = ["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo" ]

array.grep(/\D/).join('') << ' '
# => "Hello "
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_name.join.gsub(/[0-9]/,"")
```

Comment: I believe you need `/[0-9]/` but `/[-0-9]/` may be better.

Answer (score 0):

`["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo" ].reject{|x| Float x rescue nil}.join`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see it by conditions of strings checking:

```
array.inject(""){ |str,s| str + ( s =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ ? s : "" ) }
```

However following is better by all means:

```
array.join.gsub(/\d/,"")
```